# Debug react-project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, project

type here

Hi! folks as I'm a new learner of react and after learning all basics concepts i decided to practice the new concepts inside a project using react-redux, react-router and the idea of project is to display to the nurses there round inside a hospital in the week-end days and other normal days so in the NursesTour component i retrieve nurses data from nursesSlice and i check the current day if is a saturday, sunday or a normal day and in every check i mad a new list of sorted nurses by there days of round and the problem is i got the same names of nurses, and i will take a snapshot code of NursesTour component

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import {
  updateSaturdayRound,
  updateSundayRound,
  updateNormalRound,
} from "./nursesSlice";

const NursesTour = (props) => {
  const nurses = useSelector((state) => state.nurses.nurses);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [cutSundayNurse, setCutSundayNurse] = useState({});
  const [cutSaturdayNurse, setCutSaturdayNurse] = useState({});
  const [cutNormalNurse, setCutNormalNurse] = useState({});

  const { day, date } = props;
  const isWeekend = day === "Saturday" || day === "Sunday";
  const isSaturday = day === "Saturday";
  const isSunday = day === "Sunday";

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isWeekend) {
      if (isSaturday) {
        const sortedNursesBySaturday = [...nurses].sort(
          (a, b) =>
            new Date(a["saturdayRoundDate"]) - new Date(b["saturdayRoundDate"])
        );
        setCutSaturdayNurse(sortedNursesBySaturday[0]);
      } else if (isSunday) {
        const sortedNursesBySunday = [...nurses].sort(
          (a, b) =>
            new Date(a["sundayRoundDate"]) - new Date(b["sundayRoundDate"])
        );
        // console.log(sortedNursesBySunday);
        setCutSundayNurse(sortedNursesBySunday[0]);
      }
    } else {
      const sortedNursesByNormal = [...nurses].sort(
        (a, b) =>
          new Date(a["normalRoundDate"]) - new Date(b["normalRoundDate"])
      );
      setCutNormalNurse(sortedNursesByNormal[0]);
    }
  }, [isWeekend, isSaturday, isSunday, nurses]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isWeekend) {
      if (isSaturday) {
        dispatch(updateSaturdayRound({ nurseId: cutSaturdayNurse.Mle, date }));
      } else if (isSunday) {
        dispatch(updateSundayRound({ nurseId: cutSundayNurse.Mle, date }));
      }
    } else {
      dispatch(updateNormalRound({ nurseId: cutNormalNurse.Mle, date }));
    }
  }, [
    dispatch,
    isSaturday,
    isSunday,
    isWeekend,
    cutNormalNurse.Mle,
    cutSaturdayNurse.Mle,
    cutSundayNurse.Mle,
    date,
  ]);

  // console.log(cutNormalNurse, cutSaturdayNurse, cutSundayNurse);

  let content;
  if (isWeekend) {
    if (isSaturday) {
      content = (
        <tr>
          <td>
            <strong>{day}</strong>
          </td>
          <td>{cutSaturdayNurse.fullName}</td>
          <td>{cutSaturdayNurse.rank}</td>
          <td>{cutSaturdayNurse.Mle}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    } else if (isSunday) {
      content = (
        <tr>
          <td>
            <strong>{day}</strong>
          </td>
          <td>{cutSundayNurse.fullName}</td>
          <td>{cutSundayNurse.rank}</td>
          <td>{cutSundayNurse.Mle}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    }
  } else {
    content = (
      <tr>
        <td>{day}</td>
        <td>{cutNormalNurse.fullName}</td>
        <td>{cutNormalNurse.rank}</td>
        <td>{cutNormalNurse.Mle}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }

  return content;
};

export default NursesTour;
```

***NursesTour sub component***

```
import { getNextDate, getNextDays } from "../helpers/helper";
import NursesTour from "../features/nurses-garde/NursesTour";

const NursesGarde = () => {
  console.log("nurses garde component");

  const days = getNextDays(13);
  const nextDate = getNextDate(13);

  return (
    <div className="table">
      <h2>the following table show nurses round of garde</h2>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>MLE</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {days.map((day, i) => (
            <NursesTour index={i} day={day} key={i} date={nextDate[i]} />
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NursesGarde;
```

***parent component of Nurses tour***

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  nurses: [
    {
      fullName: "Mourad Mhani",
      rank: "SM",
      Mle: "9200/15",
      normalRoundDate: "12/04/2023",
      saturdayRoundDate: "10/07/2023",
      sundayRoundDate: "10/08/2023",
      status: "idle",
    },
    {
      fullName: "Said ghanouch",
      rank: "SM",
      Mle: "9102/15",
      normalRoundDate: "12/05/2023",
      saturdayRoundDate: "11/25/2023",
      sundayRoundDate: "11/26/2023",
      status: "idle",
    },
    {
      fullName: "Mohammed Gharghari",
      rank: "SM1",
      Mle: "1301/12",
      normalRoundDate: "12/06/2023",
      saturdayRoundDate: "09/30/2023",
      sundayRoundDate: "10/1/2023",
      status: "idle",
    },
    {
      fullName: "Ayoub Ghizlani",
      rank: "SM",
      Mle: "1203/17",
      normalRoundDate: "12/07/2023",
      saturdayRoundDate: "07/11/2023",
      sundayRoundDate: "07/12/2023",
      status: "idle",
    },
    {
      fullName: "Naoufel Kechach",
      rank: "SM",
      Mle: "1203/16",
      normalRoundDate: "12/08/2023",
      saturdayRoundDate: "11/04/2023",
      sundayRoundDate: "11/05/2023",
      status: "idle",
    },
    {
      fullName: "Anas Cherif",
      rank: "SM",
      Mle: "1103/16",
      normalRoundDate: "12/01/2023",
      saturdayRoundDate: "10/28/2023",
      sundayRoundDate: "10/29/2023",
      status: "idle",
    },
    {
      fullName: "Hamza Taysee",
      rank: "SM",
      Mle: "1153/16",
      normalRoundDate: "11/30/2023",
      saturdayRoundDate: "12/21/2023",
      sundayRoundDate: "12/22/2023",
      status: "idle",
    },
    {
      fullName: "Anouar Ghaydouni",
      rank: "SM",
      Mle: "1303/02",
      normalRoundDate: "11/29/2023",
      saturdayRoundDate: "10/14/2023",
      sundayRoundDate: "10/15/2023",
      status: "idle",
    },
  ],
};

const nursesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "nurses",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addNurse(state, action) {
      state.nurses.push(action.payload);
    },
    deleteNurse(state, action) {
      const namesToRemove = action.payload;

      //   const newItems = state.items.filter(item => !idsToRemove.includes(item.id));
      state.nurses = state.nurses.filter(
        (nurse) => !namesToRemove.includes(nurse.fullName)
      );
    },
    updateSaturdayRound(state, action) {
      const { nurseId, date } = action.payload;
      // Find the index of the nurse to be updated
      const nurseIndex = state.nurses.findIndex(
        (nurse) => nurse.Mle === nurseId
      );
      if (nurseIndex === -1) {
        console.log("Nurse not found");
        return;
      }

      // Create a copy of the nurse to update
      const updatedNurse = {
        ...state.nurses[nurseIndex],
        saturdayRoundDate: date,
      };

      // Update the nurse in the array immutably
      state.nurses = [
        ...state.nurses.slice(0, nurseIndex),
        updatedNurse,
        ...state.nurses.slice(nurseIndex + 1),
      ];
    },
    updateSundayRound(state, action) {
      console.log(action.payload);

      const { nurseId, date } = action.payload;
      // find index of the nurse to be updated
      const nurseIndex = state.nurses.findIndex(
        (nurse) => nurse.Mle === nurseId
      );
      if (nurseIndex === -1) {
        console.log(`the nurse with ${nurseId} id couldn't found`);
        return;
      }
      // create a copy of nurse to be updated
      const updatedNurse = {
        ...state.nurses[nurseIndex],
        sundayRoundDate: date,
      };
      state.nurses = [
        ...state.nurses.slice(0, nurseIndex),
        updatedNurse,
        ...state.nurses.slice(nurseIndex + 1),
      ];
    },
    updateNormalRound(state, action) {
      const { nurseId, date } = action.payload;
      // find index of nurse to be updated
      const nurseIndex = state.nurses.findIndex(
        (nurse) => nurse.Mle === nurseId
      );
      if (nurseIndex === -1) {
        console.log(`the nurse with ${nurseId} id couldn't found`);
        return;
      }
      // create a copy of nurse to be updated
      const updatedNurse = {
        ...state.nurses[nurseIndex],
        normalRoundDate: date,
      };
      state.nurses = [
        ...state.nurses.slice(0, nurseIndex),
        updatedNurse,
        ...state.nurses.slice(nurseIndex + 1),
      ];
    },

    sortNursesByNormalRound(state) {
      state.nurses = [...state.nurses].sort(
        (a, b) => new Date(a.normalRoundDate) - new Date(b.normalRoundDate)
      );
    },
    sortNursesBySaturdayRound(state) {
      state.nurses = [...state.nurses].sort(
        (a, b) => new Date(a.saturdayRoundDate) - new Date(b.saturdayRoundDate)
      );
    },
    sortNursesBySundayRound(state) {
      state.nurses = [...state.nurses].sort(
        (a, b) => new Date(a.sundayRoundDate) - new Date(b.sundayRoundDate)
      );
    },
  },
});

export const {
  addNurse,
  deleteNurse,
  updateSaturdayRound,
  updateSundayRound,
  updateNormalRound,
  sortNursesByNormalRound,
  sortNursesBySaturdayRound,
  sortNursesBySundayRound,
} = nursesSlice.actions;

export const getNurses = (state) => state.nurses.nurses;

export default nursesSlice.reducer;
```

***nursesSlice.js***

i want to keep the state always updated when dispatching actions

Comment: punctuation makes questions easier to read ... having a question also helps